# Angular - Use $index to load product images

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following form in my AngularJS app:

```
<li ng-repeat="device in devices track by $index">
    <div class="db-handset-image">
        <span class="phone-silhouette"></span>
        {{ relative image here }}
    </div>
    <div class="db-device">
        <ul class="opts">
             <li>
                 <select name="manufacturer[ [[$index]] ]" ng-model="selectedManufacturer" ng-change="getManufacturerModels(selectedManufacturer)">
                     <option value="">Manufacturer</option>
                     <option ng-repeat="manufacturer in manufacturers" value="[[manufacturer.id]]">[[manufacturer.name]]</option>
                 </select>
             </li>
             <li>
                 <select name="device[ [[$index]] ]" ng-model="selectedModel" ng-change="loadModelImage(selectedModel, $index)">
                     <option value="">Model</option>
                     <option ng-repeat="model in manufacturerModels" value="[[model.id]]">[[model.model + '&nbsp;' + model.variants[$index].memory + '&nbsp;' + model.variants[$index].colour]]</option>
                 </select>
             </li>
         </ul>
     </div>
</li>
```

What happens in this form is that a user will select a manufacturer from the first dropdown and a model from the model dropdown. The model dropdown will populate with the relative models after a manufacturer has been selected using Angular's $filter.

When the user has selected a model, `loadModelImage` is fired and what needs to happen here is that after a model selection, that model image is then loaded into the `{{relative image here}}` placeholder. This is currently being done like so:

```
$scope.loadModelImage = function (modelId, $index) {

        $http.get(ajaxurl + '?action=get_handset&hid=' + modelId)
            .success(function (data) {
                $scope.selectedHandsets++;
                $scope.modelImages.splice(0, 0, data.handset.images);
            })

    }
```

This issue with this is that if I replace the `relative image here` placeholder text with an `<img>` loading in the model images, each model that's been selected appears in every row.

My other issue is that if you remain on the same 'row' (see below screenshot) and change the handset image, another array of images is pushed to $scope.modelImages when it in fact the images for that 'row' should effectively be overwritten with the new selection.

To give you a clear understanding of how the form looks, here's a screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

When you click 'add new handset' the row containing the dropdowns is visually duplicated and you can add select another handset.

I hope my problem's explained clearly enough, any Q's ask.

Comment: For first problem we have no idea what `<img>` code is not working or what `devices` array data is like. `modelImages` isn't shown used in html eitherr. Really not enough information here to help with. Create a demo that replicates problem

Comment: I can't create a demo because the data is loaded using an authenticated API. Basically I want the image tag to display the image for that `device`'s `selectedModel`